# illegal base64 data at input byte 0 in go

Tags: go, jwt

I am starting with go and jwt.

For testing purpose I have a hardcoded secret.
And a route to get the key

```
const secretKey = "YOLOSWAG"

var mySigningKey = []byte(secretKey)


var GetTokenHandler = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
    token.Claims = jwt.MapClaims{
        "admin": true,
        "name":  "John Doe",
        "exp":   time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix(),
    }

    tokenString, _ := token.SignedString(mySigningKey)

    w.Write([]byte(tokenString))
})

var jwtMiddleware = jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
    ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return mySigningKey, nil
    },
    SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
})
```

and later added the jwtMiddleware to my route

```
r.Handle("/protected", jwtMiddleware.Handler(ProtectedTestHandler)).Methods("GET")
```

So localhost:3000/protected will output an error Required authorization token not found

this works.

/token will output my token. This works too.

And finally /protected with (in postman) Authorization: Bearer {token}

Will output illegal base64 data at input byte 0
I am really confused why this happens.

Comment: don't see right now where this might happen, but "illegal base64 data at input byte 0" basically means "I expected a base 64 encoded string but got something else". (possibly something decoded or an error?) Happy debugging.

Comment: It's super weird, because it only happens if I add the jwtMiddleware.Handler. If I remove the middleware and make the route public accessible, there are no errors.

Comment: well, a jwt has to be encoded (it's in the spec I think?) base64(header) "." base64(payload) "." base64(signature). So, if the first part doesn't begin with a base 64 char, it probably isn't encoded correctly. You should find out, how to correctly use the jwtMiddleware library, because that's *probably* the reason why it doesn't work. Depending on how your setup is ... could be that the "token" you're getting is an error. In any case, some debugging is in order

Answer (score 3):

Don't use curlies around your token. The documentation in many places is confusing because it wraps your token in curlies. It's meant to represent a placeholder. You're not actually supposed to wrap your token with them. Do NOT do it like this.

```
Bearer {my-special-token}
```

It should be done like this

```
Bearer my-special-token
```

Comment: This helped me with the same issue, darn tuts, thanks!

Comment: Am also still struggling with this , using the community edition of jwt-go library

Answer (score 2):

I'm an absolute newb with GO at the moment as I'm learning this right now but I ran into this same issue and realized that the code I was using to pull the JWT Token out of the Authorization header was leaving a blank space as the first character of the JWT token string. This was presumably causing the string not be base64 decoded.

This was the offending code which was leaving a blank space in front of the. JWT token:
[image: The offending code leaving the space between Bearer and the JWT tokens tring]

This removed the first 6 chars instead of 5 from the Authorization header to correct the problem.
[image: This removed the first 6 chars instead of 5 from the Authorization header to correct the problem.]

I ran into this problem when following the tutorial here: https://medium.com/wesionary-team/jwt-authentication-in-golang-with-gin-63dbc0816d55
Repo: https://github.com/Bikash888/jwt-auth